# File Can't copy from old path to new Path Laravel 5.5 - Time Limit exceeded Error

Tags: php, file, laravel-5

I want to copy a file from a location to another location in Laravel 5.5.

I've tried,

```
$old_image = "http://localhost:8000/images/old.jpg";
$new_image = public_path()."/images/new.jpg";

if (! File::copy($old_image , $new_image)) {
    //Error
}
```

I've got the warning message after 60 seconds.

> "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"

File is not copied there. What I'm wrong ? Is there a ***problem to initializing the path*** or not ?

Please Help someone..

Comment: I think the problem is in `http://localhost:8000/` this is not a location is it not `$old_image = public_path()."/images/old.jpg";` ??

Comment: Do you mean that, that will be F:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\images\ in that format ? Can't I copy an image from http://localhost:8000/images/old.jpg this path

Comment: Yes the `public_path()` will give you the path of your public folder.

Comment: But when I get the image using public_path() like F:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\images\old.jpg and try to move() then it's say that there is no file in that directory. What's wrong? Thanks @Maraboc

Comment: From where did you get the old image ?

Comment: Image is in public/images/requests/  folder and I want to copy the image in images/students/  folder. that's it.

Comment: Try this `$old_image = public_path()."/images/requests/old.jpg";
$new_image = public_path()."/images/students/new.jpg";`

Comment: Thanks, It's working now. Thanks a lot. Hope you can post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, according to @Maraboc , My problem was to get the old file.

My old file is in the `images/requests/old.jpg` directory. And I need to assign that using `public_path()`. Laravel can't `move/copy a file` from relative path to another.

```
$old_image = public_path()."/images/requests/old.jpg";
$new_image = public_path()."/images/students/new.jpg";
```

Thanks, @Maraboc For your commenting and helps to figure out that.

Comment: It's ok Happy to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the max_execution_time error then you can set the execution time in your code by setting the value like

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

or you can go to your php.ini file search and modify the execution_time over there to how much time you need to execute the action, you can set it to 0 if you want to set it as infinite